# How to dynamically change database from local to external inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to configure my docker-compose file so that it automatically connects to the right database depending on the credentials provided in the `.env` file. Connecting to the local database doesn't cause any problems, but connecting to the remote one doesn't work. Returns `error port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user`

```
docker-compose.yml

version: "3.9"
services:
  panel:
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**.env file**

```
DB_NAME=panel_db
DB_USER=db_root
DB_PASSWORD=i8sfsfdhisdu9sd8sjdis
DB_PORT=5432
DB_HOST=localhost

# remote
# DB_NAME=remote_panel_db
# DB_USER=gpanel
# DB_PASSWORD=yG8W5rxeggAasdffsdTolG
# DB_HOST=....rds.amazonaws.com
# DB_PORT=5432
```

In this form, I connect to the local base without any problems.

Now I am trying to uncomment the remote database access credentials

```
#DB_NAME=panel_db
#DB_USER=db_root
#DB_PASSWORD=i8sfsfdhisdu9sd8sjdis
#DB_PORT=5432
#DB_HOST=localhost

# remote
DB_NAME=remote_panel_db
DB_USER=gpanel
DB_PASSWORD=yG8W5rxeggAasdffsdTolG
DB_HOST=....rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
```

And it's not working anymore.

I'm assuming it's the line

```
environment:
  - DB_HOST=db
```

But I can't figure out what to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have both `env_file:` and `environment:`, the [documentation for `env_file:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) notes:

> Environment variables declared in the [environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) section *override* these values – this holds true even if those values are empty or undefined.

So when your Compose file has

```yaml
env_file: .env
environment:
  - DB_HOST=db
```

the value of `$DB_HOST` is *always* `db`; the value from the `.env` file is ignored.  In the remote case you're trying to connect to the Compose database but with your RDS credentials.

Since you declare `DB_HOST` in both `.env` files, you don't need it in the `docker-compose.yml`.  Just delete that entire `environment:` block.

Comment: Hm, it's strange, but when I delete the ` # environment:
# - DB_HOST=db` connection to the external database works but not to the local one

Comment: `jango.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused`

Comment: `DB_HOST=localhost` is wrong.

Comment: You mean variable `DB_HOST=localhost` from `.env` file is incorrect? What I need to use?

Comment: `db`, the Compose service name of the database container.  If you know the actual container name that will work too (that's what your `environment:` sets) but I'd avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm you are able to connect to remote DB? You can attach to running container by `docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash`  or run new container by `docker run <container_name> -it /bin/bash`

then use psql to connect to your DB to verify you are able to connect from there
`psql -h <hostname or ip address> -p <port number of remote machine> -d <database name which you want to connect> -U <username of the database server>`

Comment: This may be a workable option, but I'm looking for a way to change the database via the .env file settings. So that a person with little understanding of development can use the container without additional manipulation.

Comment: Sure. I am writing this to confirm you are able to connect to your external DB as .env file seem to be correct.

Comment: yes I can do it